# EXCEL VBA Specialcells read row

Tags: excel, listobject, vba

I am working with tables in Excel (ListObject). I apply filter via VBA on a table which work fine. I would like to read specific row (or row, col) from filtered table. I tried with SpecialCells which return a range of cells. But I would like to iterate as rows like listobject.listrows(N) where n is number of row. I didn't find any example. Of course I can iterate cell by cell and locate the the row via formula. But I wonder if exist a better way.

For instance: I would like filter a table with several criteria and update certain columns with a particular value.

I hope I am clear with my question.
thanks.

Comment: If you filter your table, then the next natural step would be to loop through the visible cells/rows using SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop rows like this

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
        For Each rng In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows
            Debug.Print rng.Address
        Next rng
    End With
End Sub
```